# What is the difference between =Empty and IsEmpty() in VBA (Excel)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the following VBA code:

```
Do While .Cell(i,1) <> Empty
  ' doing things
  i = i+1
Loop
```

to iterate through columns (with Double/Integer values) in Excel. Then I found a case where the test evaluates to False whenever the value of the cell is 0. I have no idea what the difference is between this case and the working ones.

If I change the test to:

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cell(i,1))
  ..
Loop
```

it works fine. So my question is: What is the difference between how IsEmpty() and =Empty is evaluated? In what cases will =Empty evaluate to True for cells with value 0?

Comment: `Range("A2")=0` `?Range("A2")=Empty` `True` `?IsEmpty(range("A2"))` `False` I'd like to see a case where a cell value of 0 `= Empty` returns False!

Comment: You are right. I see now that the series I have looked at before do not contain zeros (I just assumed they did), so the behaviour is consistent.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Empty` refers to a variable being at its default value. So if you check if a cell with a value of 0 = `Empty` then it would return true.

`IsEmpty` refers to no value being initialized.

In a nutshell, if you want to see if a cell is empty (as in nothing exists in its value) then use `IsEmpty`. If you want to see if something is currently in its default value then use `Empty`.

Comment: I did not realize that 0 is the default value of an Excel cell, but that is nice to know.

Comment: Yes use IsEmpty to see if a cell is empty. But Empty is just a constant with a value of zero: it does not refer to a variable being at its default value: its a shortcut to to vbEmpty which is part of an Enum and has a value of zero. The default value of an Excel cell is that it has no value (its IsEmpty): if you assign this to a numeric variable it gets converted to zero.

Comment: @Jean-Francois: you are correct: from VBA Help - The Empty keyword is used as a Variant subtype. It indicates an uninitialized Variant variable value.

Answer (score 4):

From the Help:
**IsEmpty** returns True if the variable is uninitialized, or is explicitly set to **Empty**; otherwise, it returns False. False is always returned if expression contains more than one variable.
**IsEmpty** *only returns meaningful information for variants*.

To check if a cell is empty, you can use `cell(x,y) = ""`.
You might eventually save time by using `Range("X:Y").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` or `xlCellTypeConstants` or `xlCellTypeFormulas`

Comment: `cell(x,y) = ""` will return True for a non-empty cell containing `=""`. Thus it is more consistent to use `IsEmpty(cell(x,y))`. BTW `cell(x,y)` returns a Variant, so it's a textbook case for IsEmpty.

Answer (score -4):

I believe IsEmpty is just method that takes return value of Cell and checks if its Empty so:
IsEmpty(.Cell(i,1)) does ->

```
return .Cell(i,1) <> Empty
```

Comment: @Christian `Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 1)) ` did you think about "Not" in ur logic?

Comment: Unfortunately, this cannot be the case on my system. When I do

    `Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 1))
      Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 2).Value = (Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 1) <> Empty)
    Loop`

I get an adjacent column of booleans, where 0 corresponds to False, while other values corresponds to True.

Comment: Not IsEmpty() should be logically equivalent to <>Empty, don't you think?

I.e. if the <>Empty statement ever evaluates to false, then the loop with the Not IsEmpty() condition should terminate.

Comment: `IsEmpty() = False` is logically identical to `Not IsEmpty()`, so there is no point switching from the latter to the former.