# Copying specific data from a column to a new sheet for reporting

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA, and I'm trying to move particular items within a column to another sheet for a report.

This is my Macro:

```
Sub DoIHaveaPRDesignation()
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim i, Lastrow
   Dim splitValues() As String

   Lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:I500").ClearContents
   Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Pair"
   Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Commit"
   Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 3).Value = "CKID"
   Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 4).Value = "Status"
   Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 5).Value = "Terminal"
   Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 6).Value = "Address"

   Set rng = ActiveCell
   Dim moveValue As String

   Do While rng.Value <> Empty
       If InStr(rng.Value, " pr") = 0 Then
           MsgBox "Haven't found Pair  "
       Else
           MsgBox rng.Value
       End If
       Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
       rng.Select
   Loop
   MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

This is one instance of the data (Column A, Rows 1 - 6):

```
 pr 1  stat RCT  commit stat P
  sys:  type 73RMD  no 1  slot: 1  lt:  field stat DZ7K  co stat NREQ
     ckid NONE  lp stat RCT  11-30-13  bp/clr 601  tea 1975 W SOUTHPORT RD
      type FIXED  tec IPLPINPL  fld side capr 1975W:279
     dist tea 7250 WINSLET BLVD  type FIXED  addr: 7250 WINSLET BLVD
       UNIT 2D  serv tea 7250 WINSLET BLVD  type FIXED
```

The code finds the occurance of "pr", but I cannot seem to fidgure out how to pick it up and move it.  I need to repeat this for the 6 columns I formatted on sheet 2, but if I get help with the first I can figure out the rest.

Thanks!

Comment: it's not clear what result do you expect?

Comment: I need this to recognize "pr" within the data.  I then need to extract the "pr 1" to sheet 2 in the "Pair" column.  Same for pr 2 and so on.

Comment: try something like this: `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row+1, "A").Value = rng.Value`

Comment: Thanks.  That brings all the data.  I just need the pr 1 in column A.  I tried "mid" but was unsuccessful.

Comment: I got the MID to work.  Here's what the line looks like:  Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = Mid(rng.Value, 4, 4)

Answer (score 0):

This answer discusses features of your existing code that are not recommended and introduces techniques that I believe are relevant to your requirement.

**Issue 1**

```
Dim i, Lastrow
```

The above declares `i` and `Lastrow` as variants which can hold anything.  For example, the following code is valid:

```
i = "A"
i = 5
```

Variants can be very useful but they are slower to access than properly typed variables.  I recommend:

```
Dim i As Long, Lastrow As Long
```

**Issue 2**

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:I500").ClearContents
```

I assume `Range("A1:I500")` is intended to be larger than the area that was used on a previous run of the macro.

I would write `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.ClearContents` and let Excel worry about the range used last time.

Note that `ClearContents`, as the name implies, only clears the contents.  `Clear` will also clear any formatting.  `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.EntireRow.Delete` will delete contents and formatting and restore the column widths to their default.  However, `ClearContents` may be adequate for your needs.

**Issue 3**

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:I500").ClearContents
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Pair"
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Commit"
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 3).Value = "CKID"
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 4).Value = "Status"
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 5).Value = "Terminal"
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 6).Value = "Address"
```

Use of the `With` statement generally makes your code clearer and faster:

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
  .Range("A1:I500").ClearContents
  .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Pair"
  .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Commit"
  With .Cells(1, 3)
    .Value = "CKID"
    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 240, 240)
  End With
  .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Status"
  .Cells(1, 5).Value = "Terminal"
  .Cells(1, 6).Value = "Address"
End With
```

I have coloured cell C1 to show that `With` statements can be nested.

**Issue 4**

```
Set rng = ActiveCell
```

As I understand it, the source data is in worksheet Sheet1 and starts at cell A1.  The above means your code will start at whatever cell in whatever worksheet the user has positioned the cursor.  If there is a fixed starting point then set that in your code.  If you do want the user to be able to control the starting point consider:

```
If ActiveCell.Worksheet.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
  Call MsgBox("Please position the cursor to the desired starting " & _
              "point in worksheet ""Sheet1""", vbOKOnly)
  Exit Sub
End If
```

**Issue 5**

```
Set rng = ActiveCell
:
Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
rng.Select
```

Accessing a selected cell is much slower than accessing the cell using VBA addressing.  I have also seen programmers get hopeless confused about the current location of the cursor when using `Offset`.  You have used VBA addressing to set the header row and I have used it in my sample code below.

**Issue 6**

```
Lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Do While rng.Value <> Empty
```

You set `Lastrow` to the number of the last row with a value but your loop moves down the column until it hits an empty cell.  If there are no empty rows within the body of the data, this will give the same result.  However I suggest you decide which approach is appropriate.

I would avoid the use of `Empty`.  See [What is the difference between =Empty and IsEmpty() in VBA (Excel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8522323/973283).

**Sample code**

The following code includes the parts relevant to your question.  I move the contents of cells containing " pr" to column 1 of worksheet "Sheet2" which is what you seem to be asking.  However, if you wanted to split cells containing " pr" and copy selected parts to Sheet2, I would have handled your requirement in a different way.  I can add a further section to this answer if you clarify what you seek.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MovePRRows()

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowSheet1Crnt As Long
  Dim RowSheet1Last As Long
  Dim RowSheet2Crnt As Long
  Dim WSht2 As Worksheet

  Set WSht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

  WSht2.Cells.EntireRow.Delete

  RowSheet2Crnt = 2

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    RowSheet1Last = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For RowSheet1Crnt = 1 To RowSheet1Last
      Set Rng = .Cells(RowSheet1Crnt, 1)
      If Rng.Value <> "" Then
        If InStr(1, Rng.Value, " pr") <> 0 Then
        Rng.Copy Destination:=WSht2.Cells(RowSheet2Crnt, 1)
        RowSheet2Crnt = RowSheet2Crnt + 1
        End If
      End If
    Next

  End With


End Sub
```