# How to avoid zeros being treated as Empty in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

### Context

I have some VBA code that allows me to insert a whole Excel table into a postgresql database.

The idea of the code is the following (the first row of the Excel table contains the column names, which are the same as the postgresql table's column names) : for each row, I execute a PostgreSQL INSERT query from VBA :

```
[code to connect to the postgresql database using the ADODB driver]

For r = 2 to row_max
       query = transform_row_into_list(r,1,col_max)
       connexion.execute(query)
Next r
```

The function `transform_row_into_list(r,c1,c2)` will take the values on the row `r` of the Excel table, located within the columns `c1` and `c2`, and transform them into a proper PostgreSQL INSERT query, i.e. something like :

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (val1, val2, ... ) ;
```

### Question

The definition of my function `transform_row_into_list` uses another function I made, called `format_sql`, which aims to format correctly each value of the list so that it can properly be inserted inside a SQL INSERT query. In particular, the blank values are transformed into "NULL" so it can be inserted as a NULL in the PostgreSQL table.

```
If x = Empty Then
    format_sql = "NULL"
Exit Function
End If
```

(in this context, the variable `x` is a Variant).

**The problem is, I noticed today that if a cells contains the value `0`, the test `x = Empty` will return `True`.**

You can reproduce the problem by :

1. Create a blank Excel file and put 0 in cell A1, and leave cell A2 empty
2. Create a sub with the following code :

> ```
> test1 = (Range("A1") = Empty)
>
> test2 = (Range("A2") = Empty)
>
> test3 = (Range("A1") = 0)
>
> test4 = (Range("A2") = 0)
>
> Debug.Print test1
>
> Debug.Print test2
>
> Debug.Print test3
>
> Debug.Print test4
> ```
>
> (sorry to have misused the quoting feature, but SO wouldn't let met format this as code)

All these tests will return `True` while you would expect only test2 and test3 to be True.

Therefore, how to have a logical test that can return True for the values being *actually* empty and **not** for the cells containing the value 0?

Comment: `If x = vbnullstring Then`

Comment: Offtopic - To format something as code, select it and press "Ctrl + K".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I would probably use the len function

```
If len(x) = 0 then
    format_sql = "NULL"
end if
```

Comment: seems to me that this is the most practical solution here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Write `test1` like this:

```
test1 = (IsEmpty(Range("A1")))
```

It would be ok. Thus, you may change the `If IsEmpty(x) Then`

---

See this for `Empty` in VBA - [What is the difference between =Empty and IsEmpty() in VBA (Excel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522323/what-is-the-difference-between-empty-and-isempty-in-vba-excel)