# Excel crashes when I run a looping macro

Tags: excel, vba

There are similar questions to this on Stack Overflow, however none of the answers applied to my issue, so I am writing a new question. I am trying to make a macro which loops through the cells in a column until it finds an empty one. It then copies some data, e.g. the date, into the cells of that row. Excel doesn't give me any errors, but when I click the button to run the macro, the program crashes.

```
Sub Button1()
    Dim cell As String
    cell = "A"
    Dim cellCount As Integer
    cellCount = 8

    Dim currentDate As Date

    Dim currentCell As String
    currentCell = cell & cellCount

    Do
        If IsEmpty(currentCell) = True Then
            Worksheets("Trades").Range(currentCell).Value = currentDate
            cellCount = cellCount + 1
            currentCell = cell & cellCount
        End If
    Loop Until IsEmpty(currentCell) = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You are trying to use `IsEmpty` on a string... It doesnt do what you think it does - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522323/what-is-the-difference-between-empty-and-isempty-in-vba-excel

Comment: Make cellCount a Long type as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if current cell is empty (Does not include anything) i recommend using something like this:

```
currentCell = vbNullString
```

"vbNullString" means that value from that specific cell didn't return any string value.

Another way for you would be that you first find last row (I suppose that you're trying to find last row in column A) and save that value to a variable. After that you use that value to save date.

```
Sub Button1()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim currentDate As String

'Save current date to a string variable
currentDate = Date

'Find last row in column A and store value to variable
lastRow = Worksheets("Trades").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Save date to last row on specified column
Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = Date
End Sub
```

Comment: currentDate variable is also a little bit unnecessary as you can save current date straight to a cell. However if you have larger project I recommend saving current date to a variable.